# Defining extent to limit labeled area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, labeling, road

I have a road layer and `"NAME"` field. I activated labels, but I don't want to show the labels outside the raster in map canvas (not layout). The raster area is my study area (you can see a part of it below). QGIS becomes slow in rendering labels when all labels are displayed. I reviewed the label settings. I couldn't find a setting related to this.

How can I limit the area to be labeled to the raster extent? Clipping the road layer by the raster extent is not an option here.

[image]

Comment: try the following expression for your value(s): `if(intersects($geometry, layer_property('raster_layer_name_or_id', 'extent')), "labelling_field", "")`

Comment: @Taras That rounds out the options i'd say ^^. Yours is slightly slower though for me compared to Matt's and my solution, not totally sure why though. 140ms vs 120ms so not a big difference either but consistent.

Comment: You both were too fast with setting up test examples ^_^ and I had my coffee though :) That is why it is only a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Rule-based labeling` with this expression as the rule filter

```sql
within(
    $geometry, 
    layer_property('raster', 'extent')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can set the data defined "Show label" in the "Rendering" category with the expression `intersects(layer_property('smaller_layer', 'extent'), $geometry)` to do this.

[image]
Without spatial filtering:
[image]

With spatial filtering:
[image]

Update:
I did check with the "Map canvas refresh" debugging turned on to check performance and I do get better performance with the spatial filter (@Matt's does too, exactly as fast actually) than without any spatial filter.

For my expample:

- without spatial filter: `Canvas refresh: 289 ms`
- with spatial filter: `Canvas refresh: 119 ms`

Comment: Thank you @Louis. [Matt's solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/471161/29431) renders slightly faster.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I meant as fast depending on where the expression is, not the actual expression (it wasn't very clear in the anwser) since both are different and could give different results so different rendering time, especially for roads where the selection will be different between intersect and within/contains